# How do I insert multiple rows from one table into a struct column of a single row of another table?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have 2 source tables at the moment.

**Table #1: sourceTableMain**

```
|EmployeeNumber| DepartmentNumber | CostCenterNumber |
| -------------| ---------------- |------------------|
| 1            | 100              |  1001            |
| 2            | 200              |  1001            |
| 3            | 100              |  1002            |
```

**Table #2: sourceTableEmployee**

```
|EmployeeNumber| EmployeeFirstName | EmployeeLastName | EmployeeAddress |
| -------------| ----------------  |------------------|---------------- |
| 1            | Michael           | Scott            | 110 ABC Ln      |
| 1            | Michael           | Scott            | 450 XYZ Ln      |
| 2            | Dwight            | Schrute          | 321 PQR St      |
| 3            | Jim               | Halpert          | 678 LMN Blvd    |
```

I am trying to insert the combine the rows into a 3rd table named **targetTableCombined** which has the following schema:

| FieldName |  | Type | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| employeeNumber |  | INTEGER | NULLABLE |
| employeeDetails | *(struct)* | RECORD | REPEATED |
|  | employeeFirstName | STRING | NULLABLE |
|  | employeeLastName | STRING | NULLABLE |
|  | employeeAddress | STRING | NULLABLE |

**Within the target table (targetTableCombined), I am trying to make sure that for each employeeNumber, all of the First Names, Last Names and Addresses are repeated under a single struct array.** For example, EmployeeNumber 1 should have only 1 row in the target table, with the first name, last name and different addresses as part of the second column (struct), each in a separate row.

I wrote an insert script to do this, but I am going wrong:

```
        insert into `dev.try_sbx.targetTableCombined`
    
        select 
            main.employeeNumber,
                array(
                    select as struct
                        emp.employeeFirstName,
                        emp.employeeLastName,
                        emp.employeeAddress
                )
        from
          `dev.try_sbx.sourceTableMain` as main
              inner join `dev.try_sbx.sourceTableEmployee` as emp
                  on main.EmployeeNumber = emp.EmployeeNumber;
```

This is the result I am getting when running the query above:

```
| EmployeeNumber | EmployeeDetails                |
| -------------  | ------------------------------ |
| 1              | [Michael, Scott, 110 ABC Ln]   |
| 1              | [Michael, Scott, 450 XYZ Ln]   |
| 2              | [Dwight,  Schrute, 321 PQR St] |
| 3              | [Jim, Halpert, 678 LMN Blvd]   |
```

(Sorry about not being able to share screenshots - I don't have enough rep. But to elaborate, I am expecting only 3 rows on the insert (employee 1 should have had a single array containing both addresses). I am instead, getting 4 rows after the insert.)

Where am I going wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `ARRAY()` is not an aggregation function. You should `ARRAY_AGG()` along with `GROUP BY` to group details for each employee into an array.

```sql
SELECT EmployeeNumber,
       ARRAY_AGG((SELECT AS STRUCT EmployeeFirstName, EmployeeLastName, EmployeeAddress)) AS employeeDetails
   FROM `dev.try_sbx.sourceTableEmployee`
  GROUP BY 1;
```

More preferred way is :

```sql
SELECT EmployeeNumber,
       ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(EmployeeFirstName, EmployeeLastName, EmployeeAddress)) AS employeeDetails
   FROM `dev.try_sbx.sourceTableEmployee`
  GROUP BY 1;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Oh, yes! I was looking at the Array_Agg() function, but was too thick to realize that I had to be grouping by for the aggregate. Your solution worked for me. Thank you!